# Better instance for XGBoost

Tags: amazon-ec2, xgboost

I'm running XGBoost on an AWS instance (p3.2xlarge) and I would like to speed things up. While the GPU is underused, it looks like more memory and CPU would help (see the result of `top` below). Do you have any suggestion on which instance I should use instead?

[image]

Comment: can you give an example of the kind of features you are using?